# Interpretation of the expiry date on a Schengen visa

Tags: visas

I am South African and intend visiting Greece and my existing Schengen visa, but the visa expires on the day I fly back - my question is technical, my visa expire on the 7th, does the visa expire at 12pm on the 6th or 12pm on the 7th - If I board my plane on the 7th will I still be "legal" or do I need to change my flight to the 6th?

Comment: Do you mean 12am, not 12pm?

Comment: Most expiration dates mean at 23:59:59 on the day in question.  So your flight leaving on the 7th should be fine.

Comment: @Tom please promote your comment per the project here http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3367/trending-our-answer-rate-to-100-and-our-answer-rank-to-1st thanks

Comment: @GayotFow - promote?

Answer (score 3):

The visa expiration date is 'inclusive', so if your visa expires on the 7th, you can still remain in the country throughout the 7th without violating the conditions.

What you however *should* consider is that leaving so shortly before the visa expires may cause you severe trouble if your flight is cancelled or delayed. Even if it is not directly your fault that you can't leave as planned, it is still considered a violation of the visa conditions if you (have to) leave later. Since there are no Schengen-wide set of penalties for visa violations, it is difficult to predict the consequences. Even if the Greek immigration officers may accept an overstay for a day or two under such circumstances, you will end up with entry and exit stamps in your passport, which don't match the visa conditions. This may be a problem if you intend to visit the Schengen area later.